# .htaccess 301 redirect to new domain by editing path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect old domain to new with .htaccess

Situation:

```
www.oldodmain.com/en/categoryA/product1
www.newdomain.com/en/categoryB
```

Result I am trying to achieve

`www.newdomain.com/en/categoryB/categoryA/product1`

Tried to do with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?voniospasaulis\.lt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://www.visaslabas.lt/lt/vonios-iranga/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I get a result as follow:

`www.newdomain.com/en/categoryB/en/categoryA/product1`

I need to get rid of `/en/before/categoryA` to get url like this:

`www.newdomain.com/en/categoryB/categoryA/product1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule pattern has to start with `en/` and should capture value after `en/` in `$1` that you can use in target:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldodmain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/(.+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/en/categoryB/$1 [L,NE,NC,R=301]
```

Also note that I have answered using dummy domain names instead of your actual domain names shown in question.

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.